# Workflow to trigger email based on the target audience column

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, email, 2016

I have a list in sharePoint 2016. In this list there is a column Target audience, the requirement is whenever a new item is added in to list an email should sent to the target audience for that item.
      So for this i am trying to solve it with sharePoint designer 2013.
    what is the steps and how to do it.. 
please help..

Comment: you can achieve this with Designer workfow

Answer (score 2):

You need to add SharePoint designer workflow on the list. I am going with the per-requisite that SharePoint workflow manager is installed and configured.

Open SPD --> Workflows --> Add list workflow --> Select the list --> Provide workflow name, description.

Add new action --> Send an Email --> Modify the action -->
For "To" field --> Workflow lookup for a user --> Current Item -->Select field  "Target audience".

Save and publish workflow.

Make use workflow is set up to run on "Item added".